# How Qt handle bad allocation?

Tags: qt, bad-alloc

What if hypothetically the system ran out of memory and memory allocation failed.

We have a custom widget.

```cpp
// win.h
class Win : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Win(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Win();
protected:
    QLabel *label1,*label2;
    Counter *edit1,*edit2;
    QPushButton *calcbutton;
    QPushButton *exitbutton;
};
```

and imagine that in constructor memory allocation failed

```cpp
Win::Win(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    label1 = new QLabel("Some label 1", this); // for example this fails
    label2 = new QLabel("Some lable 2", this); // or this one

    QHBoxLayout *layout1 = new QHBoxLayout(this); // or this
    layout1->addWidget(label1);
    layout1->addWidget(label2);
}
```

And the question is **How does qt handle it?**

Comment: It's not hard to test for yourself - just `ulimit` the virtual memory usage of the process (_not_ resident set size!) and execute a short loop that creates new objects.  Of course, there's nowhere for Qt to be involved here: if `new` fails, it throws without calling the object's constructor.

Comment: Note that you don't to release the successfully allocated objects, since they have `this` as parent, and that has successfully been constructed as a `QWidget`, so `~QWidget()` will be called when `Win()` throws, even though `~Win()` will not, and the base-class `~QObject()` will free its children.

Comment: @TobySpeight I am using QtCreator and no idea how to limit the virtual memory usage. But ive tried to test allocation failure by overloading `new` operator. ```void *operator new(size_t size, bool Alloc) noexcept {
    if ( Alloc )
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        try
        {
            void *Memory    =    ::operator new ( size );
            return Memory;
        }
        catch ( std::bad_alloc )
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
}``` and tried `new (true) QHBoxLayout(this)` and get `SIGSEGV`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Qt specific: the `new` expression will throw an instance of `std::bad_alloc` if it fails to allocate the storage.

Comment: that is, the program crashes and qt does not handle it?

Comment: That entirely depends on if you hande the exception. There's nothing Qt specific, just standard C++